# DirectShow Installation

Tags: windows-7, sdk, directshow

## Issue with DirectShow Installation

I have a "*Windows 7 (professional)*" & "*VS-2010*" installed.
I want to install Directshow. I have two questions here...

1> Should I install "*Windows SDK for Windows 8*"?

OR

2> Should I install "*DirectX Software Development for Windows 7*"?
 
   In this 2nd case, Do I also need to install "*Windows SDK for Windows 7*"?

 
 
**Please** **guide**...`void help() {;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DirectShow runtime is a core Windows component. It does not need a separate installation. Some bits of DirectShow useful for a developer are on Windows SDK. I am not sure about "Windows SDK for Windows 8", however ["Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4"](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) do have them (`propage.dll` is one of the files to check presence of).